# How to send data by intent without using finish() function?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, data-transfer

I am making an android app which has 2 activities. In this app, activity number 1 will start activity number 2 and request data from activity number 2. I use intent to transfer data between them. As I know, activity 2 only send data after finish() function is called. But In my app, I want to keep activity 2 always active. So that, is there any way to send data by using intent with out waiting finish() function ?

UPDATE: Here is my source code:

- In Activity number 1:

Open Activity number when button is pressed

```
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_INPUT=10;
    public static final int RESULT_CODE_1=20;
    public static final int RESULT_CODE_2=21;
    private String TAG = "FirstActivity";


    btnInputData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Open Activity number 2 With REQUEST_CODE_INPUT
            Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            //Call startActivityForResul
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_INPUT);
        }
    });
```

Process received data

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //Show Log
    Log.d(TAG,"onActivityResult: requestCode = "+ requestCode+ "; resultCode = "+ resultCode);
    //check if requestCode =REQUEST_CODE_INPUT
    //
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE_INPUT)
    {
        //Check ResultCode from Activity 2
        switch(resultCode)
        {
        case RESULT_CODE_1:
            //value from Activity number 2
            int v1= data.getIntExtra("data", 0);
            arrData.add(v1*v1);

            break;
        case RESULT_CODE_2:
            //value from Activity number 2
            int v2= data.getIntExtra("data", 0);
            arrData.add(v2);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*In activity number 2

Call function send data when button is pressed

```
    btnSave1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //
            sendToFirstActivity(FirstActivity.RESULT_CODE_1);
        }
    });

    btnSave2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //
            sendToFirstActivity(FirstActivity.RESULT_CODE_2);
        }
    });
```

Function to return data to Activity number 1

```
public void sendToFirstActivity(int resultcode)
{
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    int value= Integer.parseInt(editNumber.getText()+"");
    intent.putExtra("data", value);
    setResult(resultcode, intent);
    finish();
}
```

In this code, after press button the activity number 2 will close and send data to activity number 1. When I try to remove finish() function, the activity 2 will not close but not send data to activity number 1.

Comment: put your code here

Comment: Please post your code to stack

Comment: Finish() is needed to close the current activity. It has nothing to do with data transfer between activities. Use putExtra() method to transfer the data. When startActivty() gets triggered it sends the data to other activity. Finish has nothing to do. It just closes the activity after your next activity gets triggered.

Comment: _activity 2 only send data after finish() function is called_?? I dont think so. Are you trying to implement `onActivityResult` ??

Comment: here can you find many ways https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: You should implement onActivtyResult.

Comment: I just upload the source code. Please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[See the API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) of the `onActivityResult()` function, it will be triggered only when you invoke finish() function. i don't think `startActivityForResult()` is the correct method for you.

Comment: Do you have any idea for this ?